# proxy sub-subdomains to an ip with nginx

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have an nginx in domain.com, I want some subdomains to be redirected to an ip. (in the other side I have a reverse proxy that I think it will resolve the requests well...)

```
site.domain.com -> 10.10.10.1:80 (default)  
a.site.domain.com -> 10.10.10.1:80  
b.site.domain.com -> 10.10.10.1:80
```

The site.domain.com works in the target, but I can't do the same for sub-subdomains, I tried some configurations and searched in SO but I couldn't do it.
Could it be with wildcards? it would be easier. I couldn't understand well the upstream directive neither the proxy_pass but I think I need both.
What about 443?
This is my default.conf:

```
upstream site.domain.com {
    server 10.10.10.1:80;
}

server {
    server_name site.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 300m;
    client_body_buffer_size 300m;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://site.domain.com;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the upstream-directives for each Subdomain/IP-pair and adjust the upstream-name and server IP accordingly.

Then copy your server-directives for each pair and again adjust the server_name and proxy_pass accordingly. That should do the trick.